# How do you get an Android hierarchy dump based on display id?

Tags: android, adb

Through adb, I'm trying to determine if there is a way to get a hierarchy dump for a user specified display.  currently the following can be done through adb

uiautomator dump

which produces an xml dump of the default screen.  I'm assuming screen 0.  But I don't see any parameters for uiautomator for specifying the display id.  For example, the screencap app allows the "-d" parameter to specify the screen other then the default 0.

screencap -d 1

So, how would I get a hierarchy dump for display id 1?

Comment: Maybe try `adb shell dumpsys window`? I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but I was looking into something similar and it was the closest I was able to get: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58209133/8298909

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `uiautomator` dumps the UI of the active window (see [source code)](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/cmds/uiautomator/cmds/uiautomator/src/com/android/commands/uiautomator/DumpCommand.java;l=90), one possible workaround might be to programmatically start some app on the specific display in order to set the focus and dump the UI hierarchy:

```
adb shell am start com.google.android.calendar --display 0
adb shell uiautomator dump /sdcard/window_dump0.xml 
adb pull /sdcard/window_dump0.xml
```

and repeating the same steps against the secondary display you will get the corresponding UI hierarchy:

```
adb shell am start com.google.android.calendar --display 1
adb shell uiautomator dump /sdcard/window_dump1.xml 
adb pull /sdcard/window_dump1.xml
```